# Get Open street map image of an area by longitude and latitude, with highlight on specific latitude and longitude

Tags: python, image, openstreetmap, geomesa

So I am trying to get open street map image by latitude and longitude with specific latitude and longitude highlighted on that image. Something like this
[image]

The above image I got from using the mesa geo agent based model ([Mesa geo github](https://github.com/projectmesa/mesa-geo)).
I have been looking online to figure out how to do this and I found this [Slippy Map Tile names](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Derivation_of_tile_names) but I am not getting the correct tiles when I try the method that they have suggested.
Also I am unable to figure out how to add the highlighted points on the image.

I'll be very grateful if anyone can point me to resource that can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plotly is my go to for any kind of figure. If you haven't installed it yet, go  [here](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/).

Assuming you already have a list of coordinates, colors assigned based on some category, and that you're interested in points in and around Columbus, OH.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import random

#creating random data
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat':[random.uniform(39.86, 40.08) for i in range(100)],
       'lon':[random.uniform(-83.1, -82.86) for i in range(100)],
       'category':[random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']) for i in range(100)]})

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df, 
                        lat='lat',
                        lon='lon',
                        color='category',
                        center={'lat':39.983334,
                                'lon':-82.983330},
                        zoom=10)

fig.update_layout(mapbox_style='open-street-map')

fig.show()
```

[image: Figure]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. One thing let's suppose I create 2 maps like this, is there a way I can highlight the differences that map1 has from map2 in map1?

Comment: Happy to help! There's a couple ways that come to mind. You could highlight points by giving them a different color or animate the map to show movement. Take a look at the Plotly map options.